# Firefox cache bug

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

This is a bug/issue which has cost my time for at least 3 years now.

I have complex, dynamic pages in ASP.NET which use a lot of javascript (which is more or less static).

Now I have a behaviour which happens only in Firefox and then only every few 10.000 requests.

Users are playing games on my site so they are hitting the same page again and again, every day. And then the game locks up with javascript errors on the page. I have never been able to find out what exactly happens. A file is corrupt perhaps? 
Shift-F5 or simple reloading does not help. If the user clears his cache, the problem is gone.

This has been reported hundreds of times now. Every time the user has been a Firefox user, every time, clearing the cache fixed the issue.

I can't nail down the bug since I can't reproduce it. 
There are lots of reports that Firefox is caching files which it shouldn't cache. But that doesn't seem to be the issue in my case. Something else is going on.

Anyone got an idea what's going on?

Comment: (I thought it was Ctrl-F5? I'm not sure though.)

Comment: Are the javascripts in external, auto-generated files?

Comment: Maybe ask a user to copy+paste the error console when such an error occurs? Or set up a testing machine that repeats requests until the error turns up? (If it's worth the effort)

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yep. Crtl-F5. Also doesn't work. 
@Tim Nordenfur:  No, the .js is static, not autogenerated. It changes every few months, but the errors are not related to outdated files as far as I can tell. 
@Pekka: Yes, I tried to get a savvy user with whom I could debug the error. So far: no luck. I got a screenshot of the error console once but it was not enough information to find out what was missing. Well, the test machine would be something to consider.